# Eclipse Marketplace Error. Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace. Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Cannot complete request

Tags: java, eclipse

I just got Eclipse and I was trying to install DevStyle Darkest Dark theme but I keep getting this error whenever I try to open the marketplace:

[image: error message dialog]

Comment: you can copy'n'paste the error text from Eclipse's error dialog and paste it in your question, so that it can be found by the search and can be read in full.

Comment: This looks like HTTP responses are being changed (which is something what e.g. free WLAN providers do to display a login page). What do you get, when opening [`http://example.com/`](http://example.com/) in your web browser? Please note, the DevStyle Darkest Dark is a closed source plugin that patches Eclipse via load-time weaving to cheat the open source license, which might have a couple of negative effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvm, I found the problem. Arivera Anti-Virus was blocking it from doing anything. I uninstalled it and it worked now.